# timestampdiff between two dates in derby

Tags: sql, database, derby

I am trying to get the elapsed time for transaction. I need to extract it then to a file. 
I found some SQL online for Derby that does not work as I would like it:

```
ij> create  table atab1(ts timestamp, i int, ts1 timestamp); 
ij> insert into atab1 values(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
1 row inserted/updated/deleted 
ij> insert into atab1 values(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); 
1 row inserted/updated/deleted 
ij> select {fn TIMESTAMPDIFF(SQL_TSI_SECOND, ts1,ts)} as TS_DIFF from atab1; 
TS_DIFF 
----------- 
0 
0
```

The content of the atab1  table is :

```
TS                           |I          |TS1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2012-08-05 00:20:16.675      |1          |2012-08-05 00:20:16.675
2012-08-05 00:20:29.081      |2          |2012-08-05 00:20:29.081
```

The statement:

```
select {fn TIMESTAMPDIFF(SQL_TSI_SECOND, ts1,ts)} as TS_DIFF from atab1;
```

will always give 0 as the values for ts1 and ts are the same

How should I adjust the statement so it would show the difference between the values of ts and ts1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you should have two different rows: one is the start row, and one is the end row. Each row should have a transaction id, and a timestamp, and one should have a code that indicates it is the start row, while the other should have a code that indicates it is the end row.

Then, you can select those two rows by self-joining the table on its transaction id, and then you can subtract the start time from the end time to get the elapsed time.